# Python chaining

Tags: python

Let's say I have:

```
dic = {"z":"zv", "a":"av"}
## Why doesn't the following return a sorted list of keys?
keys = dic.keys().sort()
```

I know I could do the following and have the proper result:

```
dic = {"z":"zv", "a":"av"}
keys = dic.keys()
skeys = keys.sort()  ### 'skeys' will be None
```

Why doesn't the first example work?

Comment: What's the value of `skeys` at the end of your second example, and how is it related to the value of `keys` at the end of your first example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[sort()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) modifies the contents of the existing list.  It doesn't return a list.  [See the manual](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: The return value of `x.sort()` is always `None`.  It updated `x`, it did not make a copy.

Comment: @jldupont, no worries...this one throws lots of folks for a loop.

Comment: would really appreciate some feedback on the sudden downvotes...what gives?

Answer (score 16):

`.sort` doesn't return the list. You could do:

```
keys = sorted(dic.keys())
```